# Provider Hosted application often stops debugging

Tags: provider-hosted-app, debugging

I have a very weird problem. I am trying to run a very basic provider hosted application on VS2013 (Update 3). The application stops debugging every now and then. The only thing I get in Output console is -

```
The program '[10816] iexplore.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[10536] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I tried to find reason for this behavior but sadly, I couldn't. This happens ONLY when I run provider hosted application. For other apps like MVC, Cloud it works flawlessly.

Anyone encountered the same issue? I would love to the solution.

Comment: Just to be sure: You have set __Ping Enabled__ to __False__ in IIS for the respective application pool(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 solutions to this problem.

**Solution 1**
1. Close down dev environments
2. Go to Documents folder and rename IISExpress.
3. Now set environment variable _CSRUN_DISABLE_WORKAROUNDS
(ref: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/05/workaround-for-iis-express-crashing-when-running-windows-azure-cloud-service-web-role-with-multiple-instances-in-windows-azure-sdk-1-8-compute-emulator/ ).
4. Now reboot PC, start VS, load website and run in debug. IIS automatically regenerated the IISExpress folder and the environment variable resolved conflicts.

**Solution 2**
Uninstall "Telerik JustMock Q3 2013 (13.3.1015.0)" if you are using it.

**Solution 3**
1. Open Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.
2. Right click on the web project, chose properties and then navigate to the "web" tab.
3. Change Project URL to another port number. For example, if it is `http://localhost:1052` then change it to `http://localhost:4356`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472682/asp-net-mvc5-iis-express-unable-to-debug-code-not-running

Comment: I tried all the solutions but it did not solve problem :-(

Comment: Changing port numbers won't help just because everything is happening over SSL / HTTPS.. Port change doesn't work for https

Answer (score 0):

a quick solution would be to follow Franks solution 1 but slightly different :)

> 1  Go to Documents folder and look for iisexpress folder
>
> 2  go into the folder and look for config file
>
> 3  rename `config` to `config.backup`
>
> 4  refresh by clicking `F5` (debug) in visual studio and should be all good togo
>   ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/344188/How-to-increase-debugging-idle-time-in-Visual-Stud

Hope it helps